# Should I use Date objects or integer timestamps for handling dates in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

Would you recommend using

**A)** the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)-object as returned by `new Date(...)`

or

**B)** [milliseconds since epoch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) as returned by `Date.parse(...)`

for handling dates in a client-side/browser Javascript application?
I would love to hear any experiences you've had, or pitfalls you've hit.

My worries are primarily comparisons between e.g. `new Date()` (in case A) and the dates I've received from the server -- or in case B that would be comparisons with `Date.now()`.

The dates are instantiated from string values from the server, that are of the form `2011-10-10T14:48:00Z` (ISO 8601)

Comment: This question appears to be off topic here as it appears to be primarily opinion based. Without a specific example of what you are trying to do or criteria for evaluation, you will just get subjective responses and anecdotes. It's obvious that if you have any non–trivial date logic to implement, you must use Dates unless you intend implementing all the logic of the Date methods yourself (which is extremely difficult given the Date object has access to host resources that aren't available through other methods).

Answer (score 0):

I would use Date objects with a DateFormat to parse and format dates:

```
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
```

Answer (score 0):

As with many things, it depends on your use cases.

Generally, **you'll have a safer time using milliseconds since epoch**, especially if you need to manipulate the date or store it somewhere outside of your code.

A date as milliseconds is safer to manipulate because it's a number and we have a lot of tools for manipulating numbers. You can use the converters provided by `Date` to switch between numbers and actual `Date` instances when you need to do something more fancy, like display the date, get the day of the week, etc.

A date as milliseconds is safer to store because, as you already know from your date strings coming from the server, most languages have a different implementation of how they structure and store dates, but most languages handle numbers the same way. Again, using milliseconds gives you flexibility to always convert the number to the `Date` implementation in whatever language in which you're working.

---

If you're interested in using a third-party library to make working with dates **much** easier, I'd strongly recommend checking out [`date-fns`](https://date-fns.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You can get `milliseconds since epoch`  from `new Date(...)` itself.

For example,

```
var date = new Date();
var epoch = date.getTime();//A number representing the milliseconds
                          // elapsed between 1 January 1970 00:00:00 
                         //UTC and the given date.
```

I prefer the new Date() as we have multiple constructors to initialize the date.
For example, we can do

```
Date.parse("2012")// returns 1325376000000
Date.parse("2012","12")// also returns 1325376000000
```

but

```
var d = new Date("2012")
// return Sun Jan 01 2012 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
d = new Date("2012", "01")
// Wed Feb 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to show here. An ECMAScript implementation will almost certainly only have one parser that is used for both *Date.parse* and the *Date* constructor, and in any case the result of both parses must be identical. The only difference is that *Date.parse* returns a number and the *Date* constructor returns a Date instance that has the exact same number as its time value.